# How to copy all info from df.1 (countries as rows, years as columns) to df.2 (org-years as rows, countries as columns) if they have different lengths?

Tags: r

I have two datasets. Dataset 1 has GDP information for every country for every year from 1990 to 2019. Dataset 2 has country membership information for every international organization from 1815 to 2016.

In Dataset 1, countries are the rows and years are column headers.
In Dataset 2, organizations-years are the rows and countries are the column headers.

Whereas there are 194 observations in Dataset 1, there are 19335 observations in Dataset 1.

**Here's what I would like to do: For every "1" -- denoting membership -- that appears in a year-country cell in Dataset 2, I would like to replace that with corresponding GDP value in Dataset 1. What code would help me do this most efficiently? Thank you!**

**Dataset 1**:
[image]

**Dataset 2**:
[image]

**Here's an example using the dput() function on data1, data2, and data1t:**

```
dput(head(data1, 3))
```

```
structure(list(countryname = c("afghanistan", "albania", "algeria"
), `1990` = c(NA, 8376986178.18091, 178166855150.894), `1991` = c(NA, 
6235212802.81833, 181981717530.714), `1992` = c(NA, 5918963419.8809, 
189479238882.001), `1993` = c(NA, 6638424150.17767, 189895192443.625
), `1994` = c(NA, 7343128919.00223, 192204629136.358), `1995` = c(NA, 
8495890852.29932, 203691749438.983), `1996` = c(NA, 9438735430.85587, 
215925682768.74), `1997` = c(NA, 8553014290.86572, 222065225760.159
), `1998` = c(NA, 9451311882.69134, 236017418737.842), `1999` = c(NA, 
10792604265.7938, 247086651492.947), `2000` = c(NA, 11930662644.4248, 
262209398348.977), `2001` = c(NA, 13162918484.6254, 275999588714.017
), `2002` = c(19821201271.5583, 14221877961.2926, 296065702002.891
), `2003` = c(21972474898.7903, 15181621919.2291, 323276526474.461
), `2004` = c(22883102403.4592, 16414493745.9967, 346254948416.497
), `2005` = c(26245649891.7187, 17663349396.0737, 378105985252.305
), `2006` = c(28488533287.8481, 19627035264.8073, 396170566350.779
), `2007` = c(33298540638.3863, 21609262463.1327, 420644448161.391
), `2008` = c(35278625596.5191, 24251491685.4285, 439118373749.398
), `2009` = c(43151385721.8009, 25825145932.67, 449545448501.558
), `2010` = c(49924017473.1009, 28067491385.5994, 471155995344.521
), `2011` = c(51184181904.429, 29655560725.5372, 494946932460.99
), `2012` = c(59667003515.1962, 30530476595.4375, 497333381803.32
), `2013` = c(65039839448.5561, 30603951467.3962, 497987645164.952
), `2014` = c(69058343420.1602, 32529133250.6393, 506132223245.392
), `2015` = c(71831696727.8086, 33594691762.8129, 477358007095.103
), `2016` = c(75330255840.1204, 34521644436.9397, 471382327282.143
), `2017` = c(79945392645.9093, 37461287688.1091, 478068226812.184
), `2018` = c(83337636265.7692, 39653392850.8041, 496200052508.074
), `2019` = c(87250728944.4127, 41371722639.1626, 508890873330.242
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

```
dput(head(data2, 3))
```

```
structure(list(ioname = c("ACPEU", "ACPEU", "ACPEU"), orgname = c("ACP/EU Joint Assembly", 
"ACP/EU Joint Assembly", "ACP/EU Joint Assembly"), year = c(1984, 
1985, 1986), afghanistan = c(NA, NA, 0), albania = c(NA, NA, 
0), algeria = c(NA, NA, 0), andorra = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), angola = c(NA, NA, 0), antiguabarbuda = c(NA, NA, 1), argentina = c(NA, 
NA, 0), armenia = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), australia = c(NA, 
NA, 0), austria = c(NA, NA, 0), austriahungary = c(NA, NA, NA
), azerbaijan = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), baden = c(NA, 
NA, NA), bahamas = c(NA, NA, 1), bahrain = c(NA, NA, 0), bangladesh = c(NA, 
NA, 0), barbados = c(NA, NA, 1), bavariaelect = c(NA, NA, NA), 
    belarus = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), belgium = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), belize = c(NA, NA, 1), benin = c(NA, NA, 1), bhutan = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), bolivia = c(NA, NA, 0), bosnia = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), botswana = c(NA, NA, 1), brazil = c(NA, NA, 0), 
    brunei = c(NA, NA, 0), bulgaria = c(NA, NA, 0), burkinafaso = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), burundi = c(NA, NA, 1), car = c(NA, NA, 1), cambodia = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), cameroon = c(NA, NA, 1), canada = c(NA, NA, 0), capeverde = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), chad = c(NA, NA, 1), chile = c(NA, NA, 0), china = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), colombia = c(NA, NA, 0), comoros = c(NA, NA, 1), 
    congobrazz = c(NA, NA, 1), costarica = c(NA, NA, 0), croatia = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), cuba = c(NA, NA, 0), cyprus = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), czechrep = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), czechoslovakia = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), denmark = c(NA, NA, 1), djibouti = c(NA, NA, 1), 
    domrepublic = c(NA, NA, 0), dominica = c(NA, NA, 1), egermany = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), etimor = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ecuador = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), egypt = c(NA, NA, 0), elsalvador = c(NA, NA, 0), 
    eqguinea = c(NA, NA, 1), eritrea = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), estonia = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ethiopia = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), fyromacedonia = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    fiji = c(NA, NA, 1), finland = c(NA, NA, 0), france = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), gabon = c(NA, NA, 1), gambia = c(NA, NA, 1), georgia = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), germany = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), ghana = c(NA, NA, 1), greece = c(NA, NA, 1), grenada = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), guatemala = c(NA, NA, 0), guinea = c(NA, NA, 1), 
    guineabissau = c(NA, NA, 1), guyana = c(NA, NA, 1), haiti = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), hanover = c(NA, NA, NA), hesseelect = c(NA, NA, NA
    ), hessegrand = c(NA, NA, NA), honduras = c(NA, NA, 0), hungary = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), iceland = c(NA, NA, 0), india = c(NA, NA, 0), indonesia = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), iran = c(NA, NA, 0), iraq = c(NA, NA, 0), ireland = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), israel = c(NA, NA, 0), italy = c(NA, NA, 1), ivorycoast = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), jamaica = c(NA, NA, 1), japan = c(NA, NA, 0), jordan = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), kazakhstan = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), kenya = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), kiribati = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), korea = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), kosovo = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), kuwait = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), kyrgyzstan = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), laos = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), latvia = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), lebanon = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), lesotho = c(NA, NA, 1), liberia = c(NA, NA, 1), libya = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), liechtenstein = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    lithuania = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), luxembourg = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), madagascar = c(NA, NA, 1), malawi = c(NA, NA, 1), 
    malaysia = c(NA, NA, 0), maldives = c(NA, NA, 0), mali = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), malta = c(NA, NA, 0), marshallis = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), mauritania = c(NA, NA, 1), mauritius = c(NA, NA, 
    1), mecklenburg = c(NA, NA, NA), mexico = c(NA, NA, 0), micronesiafs = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), modena = c(NA, NA, NA), moldova = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), monaco = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), mongolia = c(NA, NA, 0), morocco = c(NA, NA, 0), montenegro = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), mozambique = c(NA, NA, 0), myanmar = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), namibia = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), nauru = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), nepal = c(NA, NA, 0), netherlands = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), newzealand = c(NA, NA, 0), nicaragua = c(NA, NA, 
    0), niger = c(NA, NA, 1), nigeria = c(NA, NA, 1), nokorea = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), norway = c(NA, NA, 0), nyemen = c(NA, NA, 0), oman = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), pakistan = c(NA, NA, 0), palau = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), panama = c(NA, NA, 0), papalstates = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), papuanewguinea = c(NA, NA, 1), paraguay = c(NA, NA, 
    0), parma = c(NA, NA, NA), peru = c(NA, NA, 0), philippines = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), poland = c(NA, NA, 0), portugal = c(NA, NA, 0), qatar = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), romania = c(NA, NA, 0), russia = c(NA, NA, 0), rwanda = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), svietnam = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), syemen = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), sanmarino = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), saotome = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), saudiarabia = c(NA, NA, 0), saxony = c(NA, NA, NA
    ), senegal = c(NA, NA, 1), seychelles = c(NA, NA, 1), sierraleone = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), singapore = c(NA, NA, 0), slovakia = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), slovenia = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), soafrica = c(NA, NA, 0), sokorea = c(NA, NA, 0), sosudan = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), solomonis = c(NA, NA, 1), somalia = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), spain = c(NA, NA, 0), srilanka = c(NA, NA, 0), stkitts = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), stlucia = c(NA, NA, 1), stvincent = c(NA, NA, 1), 
    sudan = c(NA, NA, 1), suriname = c(NA, NA, 1), swaziland = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), sweden = c(NA, NA, 0), switzerland = c(NA, NA, 0), 
    syria = c(NA, NA, 0), taiwan = c(NA, NA, 0), tajikistan = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), tanzania = c(NA, NA, 1), thailand = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), togo = c(NA, NA, 1), tonga = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), trinidad = c(NA, NA, 1), tunisia = c(NA, NA, 0
    ), turkey = c(NA, NA, 0), turkmenistan = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), tuscany = c(NA, NA, NA), tuvalu = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), twosicilies = c(NA, NA, NA), uae = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), uk = c(NA, NA, 1), usa = c(NA, NA, 0), uganda = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), ukraine = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), uruguay = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), uzbekistan = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), vanuatu = c(NA, 
    NA, 1), venezuela = c(NA, NA, 0), vietnam = c(NA, NA, 0), 
    wgermany = c(NA, NA, 0), wsamoa = c(NA, NA, 1), wurtenburg = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), yemen = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), yugoslaviaserb = c(NA, 
    NA, 0), zaire = c(NA, NA, 1), zambia = c(NA, NA, 1), zanzibar = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), zimbabwe = c(NA, NA, 1), ionum = c(10, 
    10, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
dput(head(data1t, 3))
```

```
structure(list(year = c("2002", "2003", "2004"), afghanistan = c(19821201271.5583, 
21972474898.7903, 22883102403.4592), albania = c(14221877961.2926, 
15181621919.2291, 16414493745.9967), algeria = c(296065702002.891, 
323276526474.461, 346254948416.497), angola = c(66025714961.4261, 
69262605548.4705, 78917776860.1134), antiguabarbuda = c(1281936562.40118, 
1384844082.52149, 1503706773.30921), argentina = c(378795278972.859, 
419925810757.108, 470169433010.404), armenia = c(10509650580.6688, 
12203500269.0459, 13847909043.0993), australia = c(564353642750.787, 
591532611248.396, 629984591318.752), austria = c(251984858807.042, 
260771892808.661, 275748269094.012), azerbaijan = c(34595460525.7547, 
38835124894.3477, 43571124846.1434), bahamas = c(9142276726.47519, 
9194285983.47324, 9525171784.26707), bahrain = c(30826319471.8435, 
33375800391.1456, 36667026445.3014), bangladesh = c(192525354925.9, 
205395060516.787, 221976201948.575), barbados = c(3523828107.5571, 
3667352806.05868, 3819247737.62462), belarus = c(66196302880.2988, 
72174548287.9255, 82603919629.5456), belgium = c(312900377877.018, 
320612812417.695, 333830859759.856), belize = c(1564774380.21245, 
1742595039.07314, 1875176919.7489), benin = c(13824774838.3424, 
14566421816.7955, 15621198733.8206), bhutan = c(1989458177.14644, 
2184936045.71075, 2378580863.09923), bolivia = c(31306422245.0889, 
32752399546.4797, 35037816257.3087), bosnia = c(19310143106.9649, 
20214975389.4334, 23340458088.5187), botswana = c(15934700074.3906, 
16981434151.7212, 17910468091.1101), brazil = c(1717826454347.23, 
1769689532880.24, 1922011086170.29), brunei = c(24523299248.4977, 
25704091177.3781, 26529220186.0059), bulgaria = c(61023165058.3313, 
65373281344.573, 70942301509.2996), burkinafaso = c(12359848400.7094, 
13571668357.0562, 14561210412.6411), burundi = c(3720415742.30822, 
3743134142.90915, 4029708575.72665), capeverde = c(1450212561.97118, 
1538833769.86947, 1741402947.53682), cambodia = c(15641120650.9284, 
17286715656.1478, 19587772827.5248), cameroon = c(34019889758.192, 
36234280995.757, 39732963801.8972), canada = c(967558830682.98, 
1019552505465.45, 1079456273708.76), car = c(2758881202.50719, 
2658440643.58539, 2893672534.04331), chad = c(8044452609.33452, 
9400116440.02994, 12899493839.4203), chile = c(162067996677.066, 
171831209720.424, 189179006543.619), china = c(4526001287014.73, 
5072700102298.91, 5735988672390.37), colombia = c(286866650066.203, 
303642993712.708, 328447014339.893), comoros = c(1062232344.84387, 
1104722039.49551, 1156241340.02368), zaire = c(22034314859.5421, 
23695372342.8564, 25972970911.0891), congobrazz = c(12123692943.7334, 
12449270155.0335, 13228898483.5535), costarica = c(34459246073.3237, 
36592824856.0043, 39207578595.8435), croatia = c(54412215447.9705, 
58312557043.6743, 62565212792.8475), cyprus = c(16716214674.5424, 
17421216997.804, 18870225579.1067), czechrep = c(185474094813.637, 
198032542823.473, 212092065914.918), denmark = c(164720383885.92, 
165958121874.319, 177856541414.866), djibouti = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), dominica = c(457533017.731854, 495638542.228601, 524509675.61594
), domrepublic = c(63649185862.2426, 63958774211.7871, 67368761759.5235
), ecuador = c(83226863410.7632, 87080715749.4435, 96767828098.3476
), egypt = c(438895222680.217, 461322134075.992, 493127762490.814
), elsalvador = c(27857218682.2192, 28817829851.9578, 29857283218.7007
), eqguinea = c(10584365243.5791, 12285432329.6073, 17410170852.8762
), eritrea = c(4075039893.03735, 4040494308.92778, 4209509456.96037
), estonia = c(16097518329.2373, 17987997014.2133, 19786074394.2991
), swaziland = c(5198632167.94441, 5500639844.08829, 5853433821.17513
), ethiopia = c(36497695584.6443, 36371996416.1919, 42420738903.4057
), fiji = c(5172647992.85621, 5321396045.96003, 5754286243.07822
), finland = c(148763741906.139, 151280484339.999, 162980164132.004
), france = c(1762926373243.27, 1751690281552.46, 1820581746307.33
), gabon = c(17996173809.1553, 18742324018.0923, 19379622849.8466
), gambia = c(2679696254.51973, 2916974709.34399, 3206689019.01275
), georgia = c(14524990211.9174, 16430841736.4099, 17850911527.5528
), germany = c(2406901890705.46, 2465749300937.88, 2583207076040.95
), ghana = c(38531824472.3149, 41288261816.1586, 44774219849.0213
), greece = c(246559427995.662, 260858583966.021, 278670064907.415
), grenada = c(826703734.528606, 921748404.829028, 940435296.649906
), guatemala = c(61922332925.4371, 64668517786.4975, 68502814170.806
), guinea = c(11417760142.8233, 11775008633.2843, 12374984222.9535
), guineabissau = c(1353309810.05296, 1386278645.00303, 1462911531.20835
), guyana = c(3361847448.31043, 3402630986.97142, 3548864259.40034
), haiti = c(12219976586.4629, 12492195088.5529, 12376577355.8303
), honduras = c(18849502622.3249, 20072566940.626, 21897625326.1624
), hungary = c(147567884018.729, 156647558815.992, 164028811074.495
), iceland = c(9351404880.8494, 9444135909.71044, 10400237472.0942
), india = c(2501105223072.1, 2747800522347.76, 3045344755416.72
), indonesia = c(1128166279126.42, 1204049454380.95, 1298670016295.22
), iran = c(759181406370.851, 840822933532.592, 901231793879.434
), iraq = c(222830525631.313, 151840160126.753, 240375164097.272
), ireland = c(138452090179.502, 144827319500.952, 157394585459.82
), israel = c(165727453304.901, 159338526106.473, 171641518765.354
), italy = c(1639680554324.34, 1671542411985.02, 1703326268974.96
), ivorycoast = c(38535391861.0773, 38717398903.2606, 40249503254.546
), jamaica = c(18105809166.3786, 19118195450.3353, 19892783422.5631
), japan = c(3588864914954.67, 3694202529698.15, 3877296161134.04
), jordan = c(34727960791.0242, 36844775713.5243, 41078299490.4654
), kazakhstan = c(148914845813.161, 165786607544.348, 186593928426.247
), kenya = c(56007069845.0951, 58720068892.8926, 63378878335.2288
), kiribati = c(141832677.161642, 147365114.894243, 148866744.91303
), sokorea = c(1019446685620.94, 1057175976424.88, 1143656525495.88
), kosovo = c(7923649512.53434, 8553444772.02485, 9013163592.77854
), kuwait = c(123128154373.255, 147144148591.528, 166579243098.46
), kyrgyzstan = c(9979766408.04434, 10879736519.3478, 11957722707.3542
), laos = c(11340427710.2118, 12251831520.4934, 13381581512.2919
), latvia = c(23223235583.3829, 25192922036.7631, 27608294804.0511
), lebanon = c(38352205918.8517, 40325090855.3208, 44176734472.0075
), lesotho = c(2767866533.75261, 2947820799.41243, 3078413642.30331
), liberia = c(3137011610.82433, 2232050855.5757, 2352193038.94176
), libya = c(97644210414.4179, 112402952967.5, 120579097287.647
), lithuania = c(36132747527.5176, 41214452084.7705, 44008465206.2913
), luxembourg = c(26222378149.9609, 27115969640.8047, 29341820786.6632
), madagascar = c(19689102226.4902, 22017083017.1764, 23798429156.2648
), malawi = c(7613804655.05928, 8197684020.30462, 8874701323.21891
), malaysia = c(329380603289.167, 354917785911.931, 389196719502.258
), maldives = c(2528456473.91694, 2929532794.57256, 3189921611.04132
), mali = c(15336761817.0466, 17046118533.2622, 17778114533.4567
), malta = c(7754899902.19779, 8283172357.10914, 8561583901.93594
), marshallis = c(144585246.99452, 144890639.710858, 150203847.082168
), mauritania = c(8350822713.83319, 9095217498.59475, 9782123425.40934
), mauritius = c(11680582116.8194, 12602481621.5428, 13502148249.5476
), mexico = c(1137595954619.2, 1183622615606.06, 1263142391486.31
), micronesiafs = c(285120758.995422, 294981392.270649, 293592427.616319
), moldova = c(10705207615.1063, 11623678408.0712, 12819921774.5386
), mongolia = c(10007490707.1771, 10907345508.4934, 12391145511.8651
), montenegro = c(4329947862.8864, 4489648519.25431, 4805734563.66045
), morocco = c(119696543290.598, 129187236500.478, 139029206433.401
), mozambique = c(10773273773.019, 11733406896.4619, 13004774181.3604
), myanmar = c(55696001978.8197, 64584074847.2713, 75319280589.0132
), namibia = c(10128463045.1344, 10753959102.4237, 12398463387.3437
), nauru = c(NA, NA, 43473161.1757602), nepal = c(30897698976.6206, 
32713061170.1723, 35166828954.1492), netherlands = c(556285472929.846, 
553482674322.596, 582518266772.469), newzealand = c(92024844754.3231, 
96525529814.2861, 102518335154.08), nicaragua = c(15194074779.2287, 
15866357967.1756, 17159053227.5147), niger = c(10227422402.2477, 
10676433245.1095, 11002838548.1813), nigeria = c(357598985971.025, 
391001358105.002, 438671520344.943), fyromacedonia = c(12919254583.2429, 
13352881144.337, 14564236605.7984), norway = c(172360885220.162, 
175982254547.413, 195208372473.104), oman = c(88313104335.5053, 
87552340329.0398, 91071166157.4862), pakistan = c(411791177792.441, 
443669638569.05, 489998729717.29), palau = c(215923164.128463, 
213695587.711897, 230365619.988089), panama = c(27064398753.809, 
28726339909.3443, 31718705894.8367), papuanewguinea = c(12599830617.0044, 
13111558518.4203, 13830943540.8171), paraguay = c(36455475847.6398, 
38736889071.6012, 41393799919.6647), peru = c(146985987030.316, 
155951348486.486, 168090446559.342), philippines = c(297631709176.177, 
318580442973.738, 348649015200.411), poland = c(450394072658.275, 
468286207442.492, 509395066675.547), portugal = c(212108753260.396, 
217839732509.705, 224966587859.803), qatar = c(66315090346.2626, 
70059331206.9783, 85772617323.101), romania = c(155640767510.347, 
162923336368.077, 192682779093.954), russia = c(1167897269467.94, 
1338656016320.21, 1473342751156.18), rwanda = c(6411073661.5017, 
6673951129.53621, 7364064824.75087), wsamoa = c(704692128.471302, 
750190113.927317, 806017219.567211), sanmarino = c(1584174584.00421, 
1676088180.67201, 1799507282.55295), saotome = c(277275940.581511, 
300990375.35013, 320938836.412435), saudiarabia = c(821341581998.098, 
930645164263.542, 1031758941643.91), senegal = c(20173356111.396, 
21921263901.0131, 23833025651.2597), yugoslaviaserb = c(54158989938.4193, 
57132356826.646, 63286953356.5826), seychelles = c(1188915593.94635, 
1139702074.97168, 1137023982.59452), sierraleone = c(3904932067.93773, 
4347875138.84985, 4759522724.55352), singapore = c(188420566532.65, 
200624771256.94, 226256929160.968), slovakia = c(71578545706.9555, 
76117131516.5072, 81725881901.094), slovenia = c(40372329697.6097, 
42088620439.2036, 45412642735.3912), solomonis = c(553860370.902565, 
600815591.14905, 647213320.471763), soafrica = c(383549133296.103, 
402193232470.559, 431832392534.878), sosudan = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), spain = c(1009753311276.12, 1055482611361.23, 1121116894298.13
), srilanka = c(86588197085.8731, 93435315263.217, 101175371578.399
), stkitts = c(806553922.275114, 793236775.248172, 847647739.179337
), stlucia = c(1462207469.87304, 1552877552.63395, 1710576540.34713
), stvincent = c(752817766.618085, 825763498.432229, 883239878.249917
), sudan = c(71866362708.0051, 78862787151.3909, 84130873607.5349
), suriname = c(3997995512.61891, 4328793310.12367, 4823186977.34765
), sweden = c(276017763557.301, 284693548208.76, 304232399561.548
), switzerland = c(274768529150.29, 276782800252.049, 289452949405.938
), tajikistan = c(8217670518.38297, 9285027298.63687, 10523815059.5611
), tanzania = c(45724150999.2266, 49681029906.4159, 54846885947.7962
), thailand = c(524046515074.609, 572153296151.711, 624510338811.914
), etimor = c(1263848756.20856, 1259226876.28116, 1298300446.65829
), togo = c(5203938767.71549, 5656788985.31999, 5752230274.85846
), tonga = c(399478206.613097, 415476650.558932, 425162787.127234
), trinidad = c(21515724139.8156, 25080076590.9814, 27802843914.0863
), tunisia = c(63372054713.1037, 67584290804.4772, 73731681385.4904
), turkey = c(607794103289.525, 634724183772.691, 727746307174.947
), turkmenistan = c(20966446359.7718, 22053898151.2306, 23780109939.7277
), tuvalu = c(25967580.3909232, 25568108.5654004, 25901421.4411236
), uae = c(332397038610.063, 368365956294.214, 414471367012.205
), uganda = c(31806422906.7394, 34494246446.0619, 37834224513.4829
), ukraine = c(240968531074.525, 268799765119.054, 309461039397.58
), uk = c(1725816341173.86, 1805058287003.74, 1917500286870.9
), usa = c(10936419054000, 11458243878000, 12213729147000), uruguay = c(31355144060.2436, 
32194625995.7198, 34715817775.0509), uzbekistan = c(69108179329.7781, 
73370997471.9587, 80958846731.5252), vanuatu = c(395208638.01631, 
419831161.670639, 448313536.300152), venezuela = c(278064242606.28, 
261262966658.322, 317359085855.579), vietnam = c(186131497707.401, 
202667942753.933, 223809287499.457), yemen = c(57722444376.6125, 
60997665592.2906, 65128343292.7036), zambia = c(19575875392.0429, 
21324205429.5304, 23438273131.6352), zimbabwe = c(25905182627.3301, 
21901900825.1896, 21185341335.0962)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Why's this tagged [tag:python]?

Comment: That was a mistake. Thanks for commenting and @Genoc for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to reshape the first dataset to 'long' format and then `coalesce` with the second dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data1t <- data1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -countryname, names_to = 'year', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = 'countryname', values_from = 'value') 
data2[names(data1t)[-1]] <- map2_dfc(data1t[-1], data2[names(data1t)[-1]], coalesce)
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but I received the following error: can't combine `..1` <double> and `..2` <character>. If I'm not mistaken, I have to transform the data in the second argument before the data1t values replace the corresponding cells in data2, but I'm unsure how to do that.
But I'm still unsure how to take the data1t values and replace the

Comment: @AlanW. that would be an issue of type incompatability.  You can change one of the columns in the dataset to the same type as the other and try

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I transformed the data in data2, and all columns are now numeric. But now I'm getting the following message: "Error: Can't recycle `..1` (size 30) to match `..2` (size 19335)." I understand the lengths are different but would like to avoid having to match lengths. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AlanW.  Can you please use `dput` of a small example of both datasets in your post by editing so that I can test it with the correct structure

Comment: Hopefully this edit is what you had in mind. Please do let me know, if not.

Comment: @AlanW. sorry, I got distracted.  Is it working now?

Comment: No, I'm still stuck, per my comment re: "Error: Can't recycle ..1 (size 30) to match ..2 (size 19335)." But I wanted to recognize the helpfulness of your answer.

Comment: @AlanW. I tried on your dataset.  One observation is that there are no matching 'year' between those

Comment: `dat1l <- data1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -countryname, names_to = 'year', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% mutate(year = as.numeric(year)); data2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(ioname, orgname, year), names_to = 'countryname') %>% left_join(dat1l, by = c('year', 'countryname')) %>% mutate(value = coalesce(value.y, value.x)) %>% select(-value.x, -value.y) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = countryname, values_from = value)`